# Capistrano - uses sudo when not needed (and fails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a rails project that uses Capistrano to deploy.
When I deploy to the server, the deployment fails due to use of sudo on a command (ant no pty to insert the password).

```
/usr/bin/env sudo mkdir -pv /home/user/website as user@website.com
```

However the user is the owner of /home/user, so it does not need sudo access.
How can I tell capistrano not to use sudo?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this help `set :use_sudo, false`?

Comment: @razvans I've tried but not working. I've read that use_sudo was for capistrano 2, not for capistrano 3